¿Cómo convertir de binario a decimal de manera más simple?
me surge la duda de si existe una manera más simple de la que tengo de convertir un número binario a decimal. Tengo el código hecho para esto, pero, me pregunto si hay un método más simple que el que tengo desarrollado. Gracias de antemano.
Mi código es el siguiente:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<html lang="ES" >
<meta charset="UTF-8" >
<meta name="author" content="Pol Flórez Viciana" >
<meta name="owner" content="Pol Flórez Viciana" >
<meta name="keywords" content="" >
<title>App Convertir a Binario el Decimal y el Decimal a Binario</title>
<meta name="description" content="Convertir de Binario a Decimal y de Decimal a Binario con un clic." >
<meta name="robots" content="index, dofollow" >
<style>
    body {
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); text-align: center;
    } 
    h1 {
        color: rgb(128,128,255); text-align: center; text-shadow: 0px 0px 25px green; margin: 0px;
    }
    h2 {
        color: rgb(128,255,128); text-align: center; text-shadow: 0px 0px 25px white; margin: 0px;
    }
    h3 {
        color: rgb(255,127,0); text-align: center; text-shadow: 0px 0px 25px white; margin: 0px;
    }
    p {
        color: white; text-align: left;
    }
    a {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: rgb(64,64,255);
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        color: yellow;
        transition: all 0.8s linear;
        border: 1px double white;
    }
    a:link { color: rgb(255,255,0); } 
    a:visited { color: rgb(255,255,128); } 
    a:hover { color: rgb(255,0,0); }

    .MyInput {
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 10px;
        text-align: center; margin: 2px;
    }
    section {
        vertical-align: text-top;
        width: 92%; min-width: 420px; max-width: 960px; padding: 10px; 
        background-color: rgb(32,32,32);
        border-radius: 25px;    
        position: absolute; 
        top: 50%; left: 50%; 
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        color: white;
    }
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <h1>Convertir a Binario y a Decimal</h1>
    <section>   
        <h2>Introduzca el Número Binario o Decimal</h2>
        <p>Introduzca el valor para convertirlo en binario o decimal</p>
        <input type="number" id="ElInput" value="1010" />
        <input type="button" id="ElButton1" class="MyInput" value="Convertir a Binario" onclick="ConvertirBinario()" />
        <input type="button" id="ElButton2" class="MyInput" value="Convertir a Decimal" onclick="ConvertirDecimal()" />
    </section>
</center>   
<script>
function ConvertirBinario(){
    var Texto = document.getElementById("ElInput").value;   
    alert( NumeroABinario(Texto) );
}
function ConvertirDecimal(){     
    var Texto = document.getElementById("ElInput").value;   
    alert( BinarioANumero(Texto) );
}
function NumeroABinario(Numero){
    var SubNumero = parseInt(Numero);
    return SubNumero.toString(2);
}
function NumberToBinary(Numero){    
    if( Numero > 1 ){
        var ResultadoBin = "";
        var ResTempo = 0;
        var ResTempoStr = "";

        while (Numero > 0){
            ResTempo = Numero / 2;
            ResTempoStr = "" + ResTempo;
            if (CharsRight(ResTempoStr, 1) == "5"){
                ResultadoBin =  "1" + ResultadoBin; 
                Numero = ResTempo - 0.5;
            }else{
                ResultadoBin = "0" + ResultadoBin; 
                Numero = ResTempo
            }
            if (Numero == 0){
                ResultadoBin = "0" + ResultadoBin ; 
                break;
            }
            if (Numero == 1){
                ResultadoBin = "1" + ResultadoBin; 
                break;
            }
            if(Numero == 0.50){
                ResultadoBin = "1" + ResultadoBin;
                break;
            }
        }
    }else{
        ResultadoBin = Numero;
    }
    return ResultadoBin;
}
function BinarioANumero(NumeroBinario){
if (typeof(NumeroBinario) == "string" ){
    var ResultadoNumerico = 0;
    var NumeroDerecha = "";
    var ResTempo = 0;

        var Cuenta = 0;
        while (NumeroBinario.length > 0){
            NumeroDerecha = "" + CharsRight(NumeroBinario,1);
            if (NumeroDerecha == "0"){
                if (Cuenta == 0){
                   ResTempo = 0;        
                }else{
                   ResTempo = 0;
                }
            }else{
                if (Cuenta == 0){
                   ResTempo = 1;
                }else{
                   ResTempo = Math.pow(2,Cuenta);
                }

            }
            ResultadoNumerico = ResultadoNumerico + ResTempo;
            if(NumeroBinario.length == 1){ break; }
            NumeroBinario = CharsLeft(NumeroBinario, NumeroBinario.length - 1);
            Cuenta++;
        }

        return ResultadoNumerico;
    }    
}
function CharsLeft(TextChars , NumChars){
    if ( typeof(TextChars) == "string" ){
        if ( typeof(NumChars) == "number" ){
           if (TextChars == ""){ exit(); }
           if (TextChars.length >= NumChars && NumChars >= 1 ){
               var Retorno = TextChars.slice(0, NumChars);
               return Retorno;
           }else{
               return TextChars;
           }
        }
    }    
}

function CharsRight(TextChars , NumChars){
    if ( typeof(TextChars) == "string" ){
        if ( typeof(NumChars) == "number" ){
           if (TextChars == ""){ exit(); }
           if (TextChars.length >= NumChars && NumChars >= 1 ){
               var Retorno = TextChars.slice(TextChars.length - NumChars,TextChars.length);
               return Retorno;
           }else{
               return TextChars;
           }
        }
    }    
}
</script>
</body>
</html>




1) Decimal a binario
Se usa la función toString(base) donde base es 2 para los binarios


const decimal = 876;
const binario = decimal.toString(2);
console.log(binario);



2) Binario a decimal
Se usa la función parseInt(string,base) donde base es 2 para los binarios


const binario = "1101101100";
const decimal = parseInt(binario,2);
console.log(decimal);




Para número a binario puedes usar la función toString que dispone de un parámetro para lograr esto

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString#syntax

para un número base 2 a base 10 la función parseInt dispone de un parámetro para hacer esto

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#try_it

aquí un ejemplo de como hacer uso de esto:


function convertToBinary() {
    const number = document.getElementById('numberInput').value;

    const binary = parseInt(number).toString(2);

    document.getElementById('binaryOutput').innerText = binary;
}

function convertToDecimal() {
    const binary = document.getElementById('binaryInput').value;
    
    const decimal = parseInt(binary, 2);
    
    document.getElementById('decimalOutput').innerText = decimal;
}
<input type="number" id="numberInput" placeholder="Enter a number"> <button onclick="convertToBinary()">Convert to Binary</button> <p>Binary: <span id="binaryOutput"></span></p>

<input type="text" id="binaryInput" placeholder="Enter binary string"> <button onclick="convertToDecimal()">Convert to Decimal</button> <p>Decimal: <span id="decimalOutput"></span>




Los errores en el código ocurren en esta parte:
if (NumeroDerecha == "0") {
    if (Cuenta == 0) {
       ResTempo = 0;        
    } else {
       ResTempo = 0;
    }

Cualquier dígito 0 en binario siempre se representa por el decimal cero, no importa si Cuenta es 0, 1 o cualquier otro número. Esta verificación de Cuenta no altera el resultado.
} else {  
    if (Cuenta == 0) {
       ResTempo = 1;
    }

Para convertir un número binario a decimal, es necesario multiplicar cada 1 por el valor 2^posición de la posición en la que se encuentra. No se debe hacer usando una condición. La verificación if (Cuenta == 0) crea una regla adicional para la posición más baja, lo que causa un error de cálculo. El cálculo correcto debe multiplicar cada 1 encontrado por la potencia de 2, sin importar la posición.
ResultadoNumerico = ResultadoNumerico + ResTempo;
if (NumeroBinario.length == 1) { break; }
NumeroBinario = CharsLeft(NumeroBinario, NumeroBinario.length - 1);
Cuenta++;

La manipulación de NumeroBinario para eliminar el último dígito con CharsLeft en cada iteración hace que el código sea más confuso. Podría ser un bucle for que recorre la cadena binaria de atrás hacia adelante.
El código simplificado


function BinarioANumero(NumeroBinario,logger) {
    let ResultadoNumerico = 0;
    let longitud = NumeroBinario.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
        let dg = NumeroBinario[longitud - i - 1];
        if (dg === '1') {
            ResultadoNumerico += Math.pow(2, i);
        }
    }
    logger(ResultadoNumerico)
    
}
BinarioANumero("1010",console.log)



O calculo el exponencial de esta forma
let resultado = 1; 
        for (let j = 0; j < exponente; j++) {
            resultado *= 2

